# gremlin_python.driver.protocol.GremlinServerError: 500: None

Tags: amazon-neptune, janusgraph, gremlinpython

I'm trying to batch populate my JanusGraph database with vertices, and I'm noticing some very strange behavior. I've created a simple test script which reproduces this behavior:

```py
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

from gremlin_python.process.anonymous_traversal import traversal
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __, GraphTraversalSource
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection


load_dotenv()

GRAPH_DB_HOST = os.getenv("GRAPH_DB_HOST")
GRAPH_DB_USER = os.getenv("GRAPH_DB_USER")
GRAPH_DB_PASSWORD = os.getenv("GRAPH_DB_PASSWORD")
GREMLIN_SEVER_PORT = os.getenv("GREMLIN_SEVER_PORT")
GRAPH_DB_URL = f"ws://{GRAPH_DB_HOST}:{GREMLIN_SEVER_PORT}/gremlin"


g: GraphTraversalSource = traversal().withRemote(
    DriverRemoteConnection(GRAPH_DB_URL, 'g',
                           username=GRAPH_DB_USER,
                           password=GRAPH_DB_PASSWORD)
)

# clear database
if g.V().count().next() > 0:
    g.V().drop().iterate()

vertices_to_add = 200_000
chunk_size = 1_000

chunk_count = 0
my_traversal = g

# add vertices in chunks of size chunk_size
for i in range(vertices_to_add):
    my_traversal = my_traversal.addV('person').property('id', i)

    chunk_count += 1

    if chunk_count == chunk_size:
        my_traversal.iterate()
        my_traversal = g
        chunk_count = 0

# add any remaining vertices
if chunk_count > 0:
    my_traversal.iterate()
```

This script populates the graph with vertices in bulked chunks. At seemingly random points, with seemingly random chunk sizes, the script fails. Sometimes it seems to leave JanusGraph in an invalid state, but I have not been able to consistently reproduce this behavior.

When I run the above script, it consistently gives the following output:

```
appuser@7a73f61a3223:/app$ python random_graph_tests.py 

Received error message '{'requestId': 'b0ef44f8-e60e-4a28-a9ef-2a25213d3125', 'status': {'code': 500, 'message': None, 'attributes': {'stackTrace': 'java.lang.StackOverflowError\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat ...org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.ScalarMapStep.processNextStart(ScalarMapStep.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n', 'exceptions': ['java.lang.StackOverflowError']}}, 'result': {'meta': {}, 'data': None}}'

With results dictionary '{'b0ef44f8-e60e-4a28-a9ef-2a25213d3125': <gremlin_python.driver.resultset.ResultSet object at 0x7fb5449ebb00>}'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/random_graph_tests.py", line 40, in <module>
    my_traversal.iterate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gremlin_python/process/traversal.py", line 80, in iterate
    try: self.next_traverser()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gremlin_python/process/traversal.py", line 92, in next_traverser
    self.traversal_strategies.apply_strategies(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gremlin_python/process/traversal.py", line 701, in apply_strategies
    traversal_strategy.apply(traversal)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/remote_connection.py", line 78, in apply
    remote_traversal = self.remote_connection.submit(traversal.bytecode)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/driver_remote_connection.py", line 105, in submit
    results = result_set.all().result()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 456, in result
    return self.__get_result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 401, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/resultset.py", line 90, in cb
    f.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 449, in result
    return self.__get_result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 401, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/connection.py", line 91, in _receive
    status_code = self._protocol.data_received(data, self._results)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/protocol.py", line 140, in data_received
    raise GremlinServerError(message['status'])
gremlin_python.driver.protocol.GremlinServerError: 500: None
```

I'm using a single JanusGraph 1.0.0 docker image with the default configuration. I've also setup an index on the "id" field for vertices.

```
  btc_janus:
    build:
      context: ./janusgraph/
    container_name: btc_janus
    ports:
      - "${JANUSGRAPH_PORT:-8182}:${JANUSGRAPH_PORT:-8182}"
      - "8484:8184"
      - "8081:8081"
    networks:
      - btc-network
    volumes:
      - ${GRAPH_DB_FOLDER:-./data/btc_janus}:/var/lib/janusgraph
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "bin/gremlin.sh", "-e", "scripts/remote-connect.groovy"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 60s
      retries: 4
    environment:
      janusgraph.storage.backend: berkeleyje
```

I've run this using both gremlinpython 3.7.1 and 3.5.8, and both produce similar errors. The error messages I've attached are from gremlinpython 3.7.1.

**Edit:**

Reading the given errors, it appears that JanusGraph is running out of memory. I wouldn't expect this when running a normal operation of adding only 1,000 vertices. It also runs out of memory or enters an invalid state when I try deleting all vertices in a large graph:

```
gremlin_python.driver.protocol.GremlinServerError: 500: (JE 18.3.12) /var/lib/janusgraph/data java.lang.InterruptedException THREAD_INTERRUPTED: InterruptedException may cause incorrect internal state, unable to continue. Environment is invalid and must be closed.
```

I have also tried increasing the memory allocated to the JVM in my container, but with no success:

```
#  ./janusgraph/Dockerfile

FROM janusgraph/janusgraph:latest

ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2g -Xmx8g -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=50"
ENV JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms2g -Xmx8g -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=50"
ENV JVM_OPTS="-Xmx8g -Xms8g -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=50"

# Copy the index creation script
COPY create_index.groovy /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_index.groovy
```

So now my question becomes, how can I properly increase the memory allocated to my JanusGraph container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A large number of chained together Gremlin steps can cause pressure on the JVM thread stack. If what is really happening is that the stack limit is being exceeded, raising this using `-Xss` can help. If you observe smaller batches working, but larger ones failing, this is commonly the cause.

You can see the current thread stack size by running a command such as the one below (using the same JVM that the Gremlin Server is using).

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep ThreadStackSize
```

Which should show something like this

```
intx ThreadStackSize                           = 1024
```

If increasing the thread stack size does resolve the issue, there are a couple of things to consider.

1. Is this what you really want to do as this will be applied to all threads in that JVM which will use up more memory?
2. Would it be better to use smaller batches, and if needed more threads client side?

Comment: Thank you for your informative response. I ran the command in my JanusGraph Docker container, and it returned that 1024 was the ThreadStackSize. From what you said, it sounds like inserting vertices, or at least chaining several gremlin queries together, is a more heavy task than I had assumed. I'm used to relational databases where you can insert 1000 rows like nothing. Also, for completeness, could I ask how I might go about increasing the ThreadStackSize? The JVM arguments I passed into the Docker container don't seem to have any effect. Thanks.

Comment: The `-Xss` switch is the one for thread stack. Perhaps try something like `-Xss 2m` . It's not really about inserting a lot of vertices per-se, it's about the way Gremlin queries are executed. If a query has a lot of steps, such as `addV().addV().addV()` etc, then that can take up a lot of stack. It's a little bit like making a lot of recursive calls in a programming language. As a sidenote there are other approaches you can investigate that avoid this, aside from using smaller batches.

Comment: One being to use an `inject` pattern where you insert a map of values into the query up front. It might also be worth looking at the `mergeV` and `mergeE` steps.

Comment: Thank you for the useful advice. I decided to go with the fold/coalesce/unfold pattern, as the AWS Neptune documentation describes it as being better than mergeV for neptune. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/gremlin-efficient-upserts.html
I might also try the inject or mergeV at a later point though.

Comment: Using `mergeV` with Neptune is really intended to be the "goto" approach for upsert queries now. One of the main reasons the `mergeV` and `mergeE` steps were added to Gremlin was to make these tasks easier and to allow people to migrate away from the fold/coalesce patterns.